nautilus file rename freezes
Since installing 24.04, when I try to rename a file by right-click on the file icon followed by 'M', nautilus freezes, and can only be closed by right click and 'quit' in the launcher. Right-click on the file icon followed by left-click on 'Rename' works, and left-click and 'F2' works.
Dell Inspiron 16 5645; Ubuntu 24.04

I have the same problem.  I'm used to the behavior in the last version, when M renames the file.  I do this several times a day and no matter how hard I try, I revert to M as I've done it so often, and as F2 is so far off the keyboard.  I can only get things cleared if I nautilus -q && nautilus.  I wind up doing that a couple of times an hour.  Can powers that be accelerate a fix please?  This is a major problem and has me wanting to reinstall 22.04LTS.

This is a bug, there's nothing for a user to do other than use work arounds. Here's a very similar bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/6465
